# SharePoint DispForm Custom Action Button to print list item

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a Sharepoint List with a Custom Action Button displayed on the DispForm, in order to allow a user to open the normal print window with one click.  I added the button using Sharepoint Designer.

The options for the button command available in Sharepoint Designer are:

Navigate to Form
Initiate Workflow
Navigate to URL

At the moment, I have added the following command in the Navigate to URL field:

javascript:window.print()

This prints the list item via the normal default print window.  the output is a screen-grab print, which includes all the background design, which I dont want.  Of course, I can manually configure my Print settings to get rid of all the Webpage clutter (background etc), but I dont want the User to have to do this every time.

I want the custom button to print the contents of the List Item in a Print Friendly way, does anyone know a better way of doing this than just calling up the javascript.window.print() command?

I considered using a CEWP in the DispForm to call up a javascript .txt file, but i’d rather use a Custom button on the ribbon.

My gold standard would be printing the List Item fields into a Word/PDF document template, if anyone knows how to do that, that would be great.

Assume I know nothing, and thank you!

Sorry if this has been asked before, please be patient with a SharePoint newbie!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to print properly, you will have to add a css file with media specificed as print only

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../path/to/Print.css" media="print">`

Then in that css file, you selectively hide what you do not want to show up.  Resize things as needed to make it look good on the page.  Some basics I've used to get it to be a full page

```
#ms-designer-ribbon, #s4-titlerow, #notificationArea,.pagerControls, div.control,table.ms-core-tableNoSpace.ms-webpartPage-root{
    display:none !important;
}
#contentRow,#contentBox,#s4-bodyContainer{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:0px;
}
#s4-workspace{
    width:297mm !important;
    height:210mm !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks BigRaj, when you say add a CSS file, where specifically do you mean? Do I insert the <Link ... script in the URL path on SharePoint designer, and link it to a .txt file in site assets?

Comment: So create a css file in site assets with the css I provided above in it.  Then using SharePoint designer, edit the DispForm.aspx for the list/library you’re working on and add the <link media=“print” type=“text/css” href=“<path to css file>” to that page

Comment: Thanks, when you say add it to that page, do you mean at the bottom of the aspx code, or in the Navigate to URL link, or somewhere else? Sorry if that is a dim question!

Comment: you should be able to add it to either the Head or Body tags on the page.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the DispForm code on SharePoint designer. I’ve tried inserting the <link... line to a few different positions, but it’s not working.  Can you tell me which line I should be inserting it into?

Comment: is the css file not being loaded?  When you're on the DispForm.aspx page if you do a view source, you should be able to find the link tag you added.  The only way it will visibly work is through a print action, so printing or print preview.  It won't look any different on the page.  If it's not loading that way, add the link tag to a txt file and bring it in with a Content Editor Web Part.

Comment: Hi BigRaj, I tried both ways (In the DispForm.aspx source and CEWP), but on both occasions, the Custom Action button (that I called Print) still printed the background. I selected the option Navigate to URL, and inserted - JavaScript:window.print(). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you have to use CSS to hide it.  Whatever CSS you add to the css file you created for print will apply when you print.  So if your back ground has a tag like `<div id="background">`, you should add `#background{display:none;}` to your css file.  You will most probably have to find it via the F12 developer tools in any browser

Comment: Hi BigRaj...a break is as good as a change! I have finally cracked it and was able to get my link to the .CSS file to work. Now I just need to play with the .CSS to make the print more interesting. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Awesome!  The css I provided in the answer strips out default SP2013 branding (ribbon, title, navigation, quicklaunch, etc), and resizes s4-workspace to a full page in landscape layout.  Swap height and width to make it portrait.  You should be able to customize anything inside s4-workspace and it should display in a page properly.